# Why is ImageIO.read() so slow compared to Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I was using ImageIO.read() to get some JPEG files from disk, but it is so slow... It takes 250ms to read each file, while Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage() takes less than 10ms (actually it is showing 0ms in my tests)!

Now I ask myself: why is ImageIO.read() so slow if Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage() is so fast?

---

This is super fast, but does not return a BufferedImage:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

This is slow (~250ms to read a 2.3MB 3264x1840 JPEG file):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it's not.

`ImageIO` reads the image within the same thread context it was called from, `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()` uses a separate background `Thread` to load the image in and returns (almost) immediately.

This is why you have `MediaTracker#waitForAll` and `MediaTracker#waitForID` and `ImageObserver`.  This all monitor the state of a image loading process which was created by `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()` so they known when the image loading has completed...

Comment: Hm... are you sure? If yes, how could I do the same with ImageIO.read() ?

Comment: Wrap the `ImageIO.read` into a separate thread.  This will mean that until `ImageIO.read`, you won't have any  image data...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The image is not completely loaded if I try to check its size exactly after the call to getImage().